# Let $T : V \rightarrow V$ be a linear operator. If $T^n = O_V$ for some $n \ge 1$, prove that $I_V + T$ is an isomorphism.

Tags: linear-algebra

I think I'm supposed to prove that both $T$ and $I_V$ are isomorphic, but I'm not sure and even if that's the right way to go, how am I supposed to prove that $I_V$ is isomorphic. Or am I going about this all wrong. Please help.

Comment: All wrong. $I_V$ is clearly an isomorphism. $T$ cannot be isomorphism as is nilpotent, and the sum of invertible linear maps are not necessarily invertible.

Comment: Informally, $$\frac{1}{1+x}=1-x+x^2-x^3+\cdots+(-x)^{n-1}+0+0+0+\cdots$$

Comment: What do you mean by «$T$ and $I_V$ are isomorphic»?

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* $(1+x)\left(1-x+x^2-\ldots+ (-x)^{n-1}\right) = 1-(-x)^n$.

Comment: Hint: use `\left(` and `\right)` for larger brackets when using exponents.

Comment: @timvermeulen, I usually use them. Thanks for reminding. :-)

Answer (score 0):

A map $F: V \to V$ is an isomorphism by definition if there is $G: V \to V$ such that $FG$ and $GF$ are both identity maps. Now consider $(I_V + T)(I_V - T + T^2 - T^3 + \ldots + (-1)^{n-1} T^{n-1})$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: A endomorphism on a vector space is an isomorphism $\iff$ it is invertible $\iff$ it is surjective. So, can you prove that if $(I_V + T)v = 0$ then $v=0$?

**Further hint**: Let $m\ge 0$ be the least number such that $T^m v = 0$. This exists by the given property. Prove that $m=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $T^n = 0$, it is easy to write down the inverse of $I_V + T$; indeed, we have

$(I_V + T)^{-1} = \sum_0^{n-1} (-1)^i T^i; \tag{1}$

here we understand that $T^0 = I_V$ and the sum is truncated after $i = n -1$ since $T^n = 0$.  To check:

$(I_V + T) \sum_0^{n -1}(-1)^i T^i = \sum_0^{n-1}(-1)^i T^i  + \sum_0 ^{n - 1} (-1)^i T^{i + 1}$
$= I_V + \sum_1^{n -1} ((-1)^i + ( -1)^{i -1}) T^i = I_V, \tag{2}$

where we have used the hypothesis $T^n = 0$ to drop the final $T^n$ from the summation on the right.  This shows $I_V + T$ is invertable. QED.

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***